# Sorting a multidimensional arry in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have below multidimensional-array in php

```
$myarray[] = array(
    'sqldate'  => $sqldate,
    'posttime' => $posttime,
    'sqldate1' => $sqldate1,
    'head'     => $headl,
    'story'    => $story,
    'source'   => $tekstsource,
    'http'     => $http,
    'feed'     => $feed,
    'F',
    'ftypeT'   => $ftypeT,
);
```

What is the best way to sort this array on 'posttime'?

Comment: Add `ORDER BY` to your query

Comment: Or if the query data is being sent to you by something else besides a direct db call where you can control the query (API call, etc) then you'll need to use `usort()` and write your own sorting function.

Comment: Actually there is no database behind this. A loop is retrieving random data and after the loop is finished I need to sort the array on a timestamp which is stored in 'posttime

Comment: @HB1963 use usort()

Answer (score 0):

As @Ivanivan suggested:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['posttime'] == $b['posttime']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['posttime'] < $b['posttime']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($myarray, "cmp");
```

This is the better solution. Please test this, too, even if the other answer works.

Answer (score -1):

@ivanivan has suggested to use `usort()` with an own comparison function. That's the elegant solution.

This here is the other solution :)

```
$helper = [];
foreach ($myarray as $key => $row) 
    $helper[$key] = $row['posttime'];
sort($myarray);
$sorted = [];
foreach ($helper as $key => $value)
    $sorted[] = $myarray[$key];
```

Comment: It was downvoted because it is a inelegant and dirty solution. But if it helped you, you could accept it as the answer.